# Xampp don't responding after downloading large file

Tags: php, apache

I have server and xampp installed on windows.
For example the I can access the server vie real IP http://111.111.11.11/myproject.

I have function that downloads large mp4 files to the server.
When that function run the link 111.111.11.11/myproject don't work anymore, page loads and loads.

Then I'm connecting to the server by windows "Remote desktop connect".
I'm running http://localhost/myproject and it loads ok.
Internet connection on the server is ok.

But if I want to again be able to open the link 111.111.11.11/myproject I have to restart apache.

Could anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm downloading files via copy() function.
I tried to set the limit on the download speed using file binary read. I set very low speed, 10kb/s, but this wasn't solved the problem.

Comment: If i open link in other browser it loads.
So something related to the session? session id?

Comment: If I remove the session from the browser it starts load again